# The city of Erebor

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

What happens to the city of Erebor  after the Hobbit series? Because  the city doesn't show up in the Lord of the rings series.

Comment: Erebor refers to the Lonely Mountain. Do you mean Lake-Town (Esgaroth)?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - Erebor is the name of the Dwarven city where Smaug lived. It's also the name of the surrounding kingdom.

Comment: And of the mountain as well. The city and kingdom are eponymous.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing that out. I've only ever really considered it a name for the mountain, but I guess the kingdom was also named for it, too.

Answer (score 27):

Dain, who becomes the ruler of Erebor after the death of Thorin, is mentioned several times in *The Lord of the Rings*. He is the one who sends Gloin and Gimli to Rivendell:

> 'And so I have been sent at last by Dain to warn Bilbo that he is sought by the Enemy, and to learn, if may be, why he desires this ring, this least of rings. Also we crave the advice of Elrond. For the Shadow grows and draws nearer. We discover that messengers have come also to King Brand in Dale, and that he is afraid. We fear that he may yield. Already war is gathering on his eastern borders. If we make no answer, the Enemy may move Men of his rule to assail King Brand, and Dain also.'

(*The Lord of the Rings*, Book II, Chapter 2, "The Council of Elrond")

In fact, near the end of the War of the Ring:

> At the same time as the great armies besieged Minas Tirith, a host of the allies of Sauron that had long threatened the borders of King Brand crossed the River Carnen, and Brand was driven back to Dale. There he had the aid of the Dwarves of Erebor; and there was a great battle at the Mountain's feet. It lasted three days, but in the end both King Brand and King Dáin Ironfoot were slain, and the Easterlings had the victory. But they could not take the Gate. And many, both Dwarves and Men, took refuge in Erebor, and there withstood a siege.

(*The Lord of the Rings*, Appendix B)

Thus, the Kingdom of Erebor lived on after the War of the Ring, ruled by Dain's son Thorin III Stonehelm.

Answer (score 11):

Erebor does still exist in the Lord of the Rings timescale, although it didn't make it into the movies.

Following the events of The Hobbit, Dain Ironfoot became King Under the Mountain.  Balin's doomed expedition to Moria set out from Erebor, Gimli came to Rivendell from Erebor, and there was a battle and siege there during the War of the Ring (cited from Appendix B, The Tale of Years):

> At the same time as the great armies besieged Minas Tirith a host of the allies of Sauron that had long threatened the borders of King Brand crossed the River Carnen, and Brand was driven back to Dale. There he had the aid of the Dwarves of Erebor; and there was a great battle at the Mountain's feet It lasted three days, but in the end both King Brand and King Dáin Ironfoot were slain, and the Easterlings had the victory. But they could not take the Gate, and many, both Dwarves and Men, took refuge in Erebor, and there withstood a siege.

Appendix A to Lord of the Rings notes that Gimli came to the Glittering Caves with some of folk of Erebor and became a Dwarf-lord there before tradition has him sailing West with Legolas:

> We have heard tell that Legolas took Gimli Glóin's son with him because of their great friendship, greater than any that has been between Elf and Dwarf. If this is true, then it is strange indeed: that a Dwarf should be willing to leave Middle-earth for any love, or that the Eldar should receive him, or that the Lords of the West should permit it. But it is said that Gimli went also out of desire to see again the beauty of Galadriel; and it may be that she, being mighty among the Eldar, obtained this grace for him. More cannot be said of this matter.

In other words, Erebor was repopulated and reinstated as a Dwarf kingdom.

Comment: Dangit, you beat me again. Hmfy.